# How do I sort a nested object by a property?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to be able to sort the nested object below from the lowest number to the high number...

```js
{
  "a": 50,
  "b": {
    "c": {
      "d": 69,
      "e": 420,
      "f": 21,
      "g": {
        "h": 5,
        "i": 3,
      }
    }
  },
  "j": 1,
  "k": 1000
}
```

... so that it can look like this:

```js
{
  "j": 1, // min in OBJECT
  "b": {
    "c": { // min in B
      "g": { // min in C
        "i": 3, // min in G
        "h": 5
      },
      "f": 21,
      "d": 69,
      "e": 420
    }
  },
  "a": 50,
  "k": 1000
}
```

Note that the object is sorted by the lowest number inside objects, meaning the object's direct children's values are [1, 3, 50, 1000].

Comment: you mean `1,50, 1000` since the `3` is the value of `.a.b.c.g.i` which is about as far away from direct child as you can get in your object

Comment: @JaromandaX I put the `3` there since it is what makes `object.b` the second in order (3 is the lowest value in `object.b`.

Comment: Have you tried writing code yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty using Object.entries, Array forEach, Array reduce and Array sort

`getpaths` creates an array in the form

```
[
    ["a.b.c", 2],
    ["d.e", 1],
    ....
]
```

> not really happy with the code for `getpaths` - if someone has better code, please let me know

Which can then be sorted easily using Array sort

`createPath` takes a root object, a path and a value and creates the "path" in the object

so, given `{}, "a.b.c", 2`

would result in

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 2
    }
  }
}
```

Since (non numeric) object keys are "sorted" in insertion order [[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description)], inserting the values in value order produces the object as required

```js
let obj = { a: 50, b: { c: { d: 69, e: 420, f: 21, g: { h: 5, i: 3, }, }, }, j: 1, k: 1000 };

const getpaths = (obj) => {
    const paths = [];
    const fn = (obj, path = "") => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                return fn(value, `${path}.${key}`);
            }
            paths.push([`${path}.${key}`.slice(1), value]);
        });
    };
    fn(obj);
    return paths;
};
const createPath = (obj, [path, value]) => {
    path.split(".").reduce(
        (acc, key, index, array) => acc[key] ||= array[index + 1] ? {} : value, obj);
        
    return obj;
};

const result = getpaths(obj)
    .sort(([, a], [, b]) => a - b)
    .reduce((acc, item) => createPath(acc, item), {});
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: Very nice. Do you think a reference to "object keys are "sorted" in insertion order" (perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description ?) is necessary?

Comment: Is there a way to replace the `||=`?

Comment: @nick - I thought I did :p

Comment: @Aetinx `x ||= y` is short (modern?) for `x = x || y`

Comment: @JaromandaX Cool! I'll try that when I get back onto my computer. (Currently on my phone)